# Troubleshoot orientation changing issue

Tags: android

In one of my application, there are multiple `Activity`(s),
Mostly all activities are configured to be in Landscape orientation by providing `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` for each activity
in android manifest file. But one of the activity called 'MyDashBoardActivity' changes orientation to Portrait automatically, when that Activity starts in one of my Android device, but it works fine (Loads in Landscape orientation as expected) in other devices.

How can troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: I think you should use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` and/or `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, without "sensor" notions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

And write In your onCreate :

after `setContentView();`

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try    
`myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

or

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  android:name="MyDashBoardActivity"/>
```